# Squid ICAP Rewriting Content

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, squid, content-adaptation

I have a need for the following:

1. Web App at `http://mything.com/`.
2. Reverse Proxy Server at `http://mything.com/proxy/`

   1. Reverse Proxy should proxy: `http://mything.com/proxy/http://bbc.co.uk/` for example.
3. The Reverse Proxy should rewrite all links, src, href, and so forth in the source page (`htp://bbc.co.uk`) to rebase them from `http://mything.com/proxy/$1`.

We have a 90% working implementation in Ruby, developed as a *Rack* app, a series of 8 middlewares that do various jobs:

- Rewrite cookie domain
- Inject a javascript chunk from our site
- Rewrite links to fit the proxy.

Admittedly our Ruby version isn't bad, but it requires about one second to process a page, which is shockingly slow, and simply doesn't blend. It gets an order of magnitude worse when we bring SSL into the mix, and the management are talking about stripping all SSL out, and only working with http. (Which naturally is short sighted, and incredibly foolish.)

This kind of problem simply has to have been more widely solved by tools such as Squid and protocol drafts such as ICAP.

I'd like to move away from our home grown solution as it's a source of constant pain, and it's **slow**.

I've just come to learn about *Squid*'s [*Content Adaptation*](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ContentAdaptation) function, but haven't been able to find a decent way to make it work.

I can see the following problems which I haven't been able to solve:

1. How to extract the URL component from the original request URI?
   i.e how can I take `.../proxy/(.*)` and use that as the backend address?
2. How to rewrite cookies in an ICAP program?
   i.e does the ICAP content adaptation program receive the full request?
3. How to rewrite urls, links, etc with ICAP? ([Squirm](http://squirm.foote.com.au/) looks promising, but looks like things have to be hard coded (see point #1.)
   i.e are there any smarter tools that simply using regexes/etc?

I know this question is at risk of being flagged *"demonstrates no evidence of research"*, but I'm at the limits of what I've been able to ascertain without investing a number of days (or so it would appear) to learn the intricacies of Squid, when the only thing I need is to rewrite some content!